# AWS EB continua instalando mysqlclient mesmo após ter removido do requirements.txt

Tags: django, amazon-aws, elastic-beanstalk

Estou fazendo o deploy de uma aplicação Django para a AWS Elastic Beanstalk, e há um erro em particular que não consigo sair dele, e não percebo porque. Toda vez que faço deploy, ele me dá um erro de instalação com o **mysqlclient**, e isso acontece até mesmo após a package ter sido removida do requirements, ou seja, não tem o porque instala-la. E então, acontece a coisa mais esquisita de sempre, exemplo de log abaixo:

```
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/79/67ddf24ac31b05d741f0ac87fa612c7a11bab1b39b8270ed7344d149f8af/mysqlclient-1.4.2.tar.gz#sha256=b95edaa41d6cc47deecabcdcbb5ab437ad9ae6d8955f5cf10d1847b37e66ef5e (from https://pypi.org/simple/mysqlclient/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/python3.9 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-50nldfyq/mysqlclient_4ca10c8c3bec43fb92bb404b674be207/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-50nldfyq/mysqlclient_4ca10c8c3bec43fb92bb404b674be207/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-bpnriwn_
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-50nldfyq/mysqlclient_4ca10c8c3bec43fb92bb404b674be207/
  Complete output (10 lines):
  /bin/sh: line 1: mysql_config: command not found
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-50nldfyq/mysqlclient_4ca10c8c3bec43fb92bb404b674be207/setup.py", line 16, in <module>
      metadata, options = get_config()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-50nldfyq/mysqlclient_4ca10c8c3bec43fb92bb404b674be207/setup_posix.py", line 51, in get_config
      libs = mysql_config("libs")
    File "/tmp/pip-install-50nldfyq/mysqlclient_4ca10c8c3bec43fb92bb404b674be207/setup_posix.py", line 29, in mysql_config
      raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (_mysql_config_path,))
  OSError: mysql_config not found
```

E insiste em instalar todas as versões, também :

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Downloading mysqlclient-2.2.0.tar.gz (89 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-2.1.1.tar.gz (88 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-2.1.0.tar.gz (87 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-2.0.3.tar.gz (88 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-2.0.2.tar.gz (88 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-2.0.1.tar.gz (87 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-2.0.0.tar.gz (87 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.4.6.tar.gz (85 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.4.5.tar.gz (86 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.4.4.tar.gz (86 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.4.3.tar.gz (86 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.4.2.post1.tar.gz (85 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.4.2.tar.gz (85 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.4.1.tar.gz (85 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.4.0.tar.gz (85 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.3.14.tar.gz (91 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.3.13.tar.gz (90 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz (89 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.3.11.tar.gz (89 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.3.10.tar.gz (82 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.3.9.tar.gz (81 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.3.8.tar.gz (81 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.3.7.tar.gz (79 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.3.6.tar.gz (78 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.3.5.tar.gz (77 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.3.4.tar.gz (77 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.3.3.tar.gz (77 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.3.2.tar.gz (77 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.3.1.tar.gz (76 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.3.0.tar.gz (76 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
```

Eu estou usando a plataforma Python 3.9 Amazon Linux 2023, e não há nada no meu requirements que peça que este instale o mysqlclient.
Podem ajudar? Já estou há 1 dia tentando entender este problema.

Comment: Encontrei referência desse erro, mas pelo que vi basta instalar as dependências do sistema operacional. Mais especificamente as dependências `libmysqlclient-dev` e  `python-dev`. Supondo que o sistema operacional é um debian/ubuntu, o comando para instalar as dependências é o seguinte: `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev python-dev`. Mas você pode instalar as dependências equivalentes para a sua distribuição do Linux. Mais informações nesta [publicação](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12814672/4598175)

Comment: @Danizavtz, consegui entender o que estava faltando, são os packages: 
`python3-devel.x86_64: [] mariadb105-devel.x86_64: []` Não cheguei a entender o porque que era instalado o mysqlclient sempre que fizesse o comando para criar um ambiente virtual `eb create`. mas, entretanto, eu consegui resolver e agora o deploy foi feito sem erros na instalação do mysqlclient. Obrigado

Comment: Muito bom, parabéns.